# How gulp task converts scss to css?

Tags: sass, gulp

How gulp converts scss to css, i know that we can define task to convert scss to css but my question is how that conversion takes place.Which technology does it uses to convert scss to css.

Comment: It is unclear what are you talking about. Gulp is just a task runner. If you want someone to explain a task (in this case, converting scss to css), you need to provide a link to code either code in your question. Without it the question will be closed without an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the source of the plugin itself in your npm directory and see for yourself